# How to crop an image into a sector in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry

I am trying to find a way to turn a circle into segments in Javascript and then download the resulting sectors in image files that are sector-shaped. However, I am unsure how to make sectors from an image and download the resulting sector *without any background* (I do not want to create a square image and instead want to make a sector-shaped image). I tried cropping images with HTML Canvas (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35188022/how-to-cut-an-image-html-canvas-in-half-via-javascript) for the cropping method I used), but I could not find a way to cut the image into a sector instead of a rectangle and download the image as a sector instead of a rectangle. How should I go about programming this problem? Here is an example of what I want to do (I used photoshop):

Given [this circular image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjEut.png), I want to cut it into four equally-sized sectors programmatically: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dI4HZ.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEa9S.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNm65.png), [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swuvK.png).

Comment: Do you know any image format that does support non rectangular images? If there is, I bet there isn't much consumer able to display it. What's wrong with a rectangular image that has transparent pixels?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am fine using a rectangular image if the background is transparent. I am mainly looking for a way to cut an image into sectors?